# Configure Apache as a Reverse Proxy To Point Tomcat On GoDaddy VPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, vps

I need to setup reverse proxy on godaddy vps (Cent OS, Apache 2.4) to transfer request from Apache port 80 to my Java application running on tomcat 7.
I have come across a various answers but nothing works. Even on godaddy site they provide some way to configure the reverse proxy but its not work.
Please provide me some help or point me in right direction.

Following are the sites that i already try
[GoDaddy VPS](https://in.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Tie-Root-domain-www-mydomain-com-to-apache-tomcat-application/m-p/50806) its official GoDaddy help page but unfortunately didn't work another site [Xampp Virtual Host](http://www.solutionsatexperts.com/xampp-virtual-host-configuration/) and [Proxy Baypass](http://www.solutionsatexperts.com/xampp-web-server-apache-integration-with-tomcat-apache-using-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse/). I try other solutions like changing Tomcat port to 80 its work but i dont want to do that. I also change .htaccess configuration but unable to access Apache.
Kindly please help.